# Displaying a function with DOM methods

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I'm teaching myself through The Odin Project. The first project was running a rock paper scissors game through the console need help changing it to now running in the browser with DOM methods

```
function game() {
        let Win = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          Win += playRound;
        }
        if (3 > win) {
          alert("You lose");
        } else if (Win > 2) {
          alert("You Win");
        }
      }
```

This is my function to say how rounds into the game is won, stuck on how to display on the browser, need some direction. I'm thinking creating an element(div) then a listener?